# Erro java.lang.NillPointerException

Tags: java

Meu código está retornando este erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NillPointerException at BAnco.java:36

Já refiz o projeto todo, todas as classes, assisti inúmeras vezes os vídeos, mas não estou sabendo identificar a causa do erro.

Meu código:

```
public class ContaJ implements Conta {

private double saldo = 0.0;

// Taxa de juros aplicada
public static final double I = 0.05;

public void extrato() {
System.out.println("Saldo da conta F" + saldo);

}


public void deposito(double valor) {
saldo = saldo + valor;
System.out.println("Valor depositado:" + valor);
}


public void saque(double valor) {
if (valor <= saldo) { 
saldo = saldo - valor;
System.out.println("Valor sacado:"+ valor);
}
else {
System.out.println("Saldo insuficinete");
}
}

public double simulaEmprestimo (double cf, int n) {
return I/(1-1/Math.pow(1+I, n))*cf;
}
}

====================================================
public class ContaF implements Conta {

private double saldo = 0.0;

// Taxa de juros aplicada
public static final double I = 0.03;

public void extrato() {
System.out.println("Slado da conta F" + saldo);

}


public void deposito(double valor) {
saldo = saldo + valor;
System.out.println("Valor depositado:" + valor);
}


public void saque(double valor) {
if (valor <= saldo) { 
saldo = saldo - valor;
System.out.println("Valor sacado:"+ valor);
}
else {
System.out.println("Saldo insuficinete");
}
}

public double simulaEmprestimo (double cf, int n) {
return I/(1-1/Math.pow(1+I, n))*cf;
}
}

=============================================
public interface Conta {

public void extrato();
public void deposito(double valor);
public void saque(double valor);

// cf = capital financiado, n = meses
public double simulaEmprestimo (double cf, int n);

}

=======================================
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BAnco {

public static void main (String args[]) {


ArrayList<correntistamae> lista_De_Clientes = new ArrayList<correntistamae>();

Correntista c1 = new Correntista("Matheus", new ContaF());
lista_De_Clientes.add(c1);
Correntista c2 = new Correntista("Arlindo",  new ContaF());
lista_De_Clientes.add(c2);
Correntista c3 = new Correntista("Josefanilda",  new ContaF());
lista_De_Clientes.add(c3);
Correntista c4 = new Correntista("Jucintolucio",  new ContaF());
lista_De_Clientes.add(c4);

Corrrentista_Juridico cJuridico = new Corrrentista_Juridico("ACME LLC", "Pedro",  new ContaJ());
lista_De_Clientes.add(cJuridico);



c1.exibe_Indentfiacao();
c2.exibe_Indentfiacao();
c3.exibe_Indentfiacao();
c4.exibe_Indentfiacao();
cJuridico.exibe_Indentfiacao();

double valorParcela = c1.getConta().simulaEmprestimo(1000.0, 12);
System.out.println(valorParcela); //Dando erro



} 
}
```

O que está causando este erro?

Comment: Cadê a classe de Correntista?

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo que você edite sua pergunta e poste a classe Correntista para fazermos uma análise mais aprofundada.

No entanto,tomando como referência o método simulaEmprestimo() da classe ContaJ e ContaF, o seu problema pode estar em **c1.getConta()**, levando em consideração que ***simulaEmprestimo(1000.0, 12)*** compilaria normalmente:

```
double valorParcela = c1.getConta().simulaEmprestimo(1000.0, 12);
```

Análise melhor o método getConta() de Correntista, pois o problema pode estar ai.

Poste a classe Correntista para que possamos te ajudar.